# Is colon : valid in attribute names for HTML(5)?

Tags: html

Is a colon : character valid an attribute name in HTML(5)?

Like this:

```
<p he:llo="world" >Hello world</p>
```

After searching the web I found this article:

http://razzed.com/2009/01/30/valid-characters-in-attribute-names-in-htmlxml/

That says it's valid, but he links to this w3-document:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name

But this article is entitled "Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Second Edition)" - meaning, XML and not HTML.

Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: HTML is a derivative of XML. So, I guess it is possible. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Strictly, HTML is a *cousin* of XML, not a derivative (they are both derived from an older standard called SGML).

Comment: HTML 4.x and earlier as SGML applications. XML is a derivative of SGML. XHTML is an XML application. HTML 5 isn't an SGML or XML application, although it has an XML serialisation that is.

Comment: Fails W3 validation with "Attribute he:llo is not serializable as XML 1.0." and "Attribute he:llo not allowed on element p at this point.".

Comment: What is the practical problem behind this question? The attribute `he:llo` is not valid in any version of HTML. Some attributes with a colon in their name are valid in some versions of HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is used for XML namespaces and should not be used for other purposes as per that document you referenced:

> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML Names] assigns a meaning to
>   names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not use
>   the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but XML
>   processors must accept the colon as a name character.

[HTML5 supports both an XML mode and a non-XML mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#syntax). I would stay away from colons except as namespace delimiters.